binary timeserie to binary timeserie regression
I'm looking for a way to determine which of my predictive variables (binary time series) best explains my response variable (also a binary time series).
Basically, I ask people to listen to audio files and tap to the beat. I want to know which rythmic_feature explains the tapping better. I'm only interested in the temporal aspect. 1 code for an event. Here is an example of data for one trial (one audio file for one participant):
1-second audio file, fs = 10Hz (in reality, the audio files are longer with higher fs).
rythmic_feature 1 = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
rythmic_feature 2 = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
rythmic_feature 3 = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
tapping = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1] --> (participant taps = 1)
What do you think is the best/easiest way to compute this, given that I'm quite a beginner in statistics and code? :) I'm coding in Python and R. I'm afraid of using a model that is not fully adapted to my data ...Thank you for your help!
